# User not able to authenticate using AD account - Authentication failure

Tags: linux

User not able to authenticate using AD account where other users are able to log in and user get an incorrect password error

if you run into this issue and notice the following error in your system logs then your issue is just to rejoin the domain

```
FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/tty1' FOR 'MYLOGINID', Authentication failure


Failed to initialize credentials using keytab [MEMORY:/etc/krb5.keytab]: Preauthentication failed. Unable to create GSSAPI-encrypted LDAP connection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by just re-joining with a domain controller.

take a backup of your config file:  `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`

```
#realm leave

#realm realm join -U admin myad.com
```